# Difference between -fileHandleForWritingAtPath: and fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsfilehandle

For me it sounds like the same thing. Updating a file implies to write to the file. Writing to a file is also an update for me. But I guess there's a subtle difference ;-)

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fileHandleForWritingAtPath:` returns an object that responds only to `writeData:`.

`fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:` responds to both NSFileHandle read... messages and `writeData:`.